# When moving faces, some sides stay in their original place

Tags: modeling

When moving faces, some sides stay in their original place. Everything is selected, but sometimes when I go to move a face one of the sides moves, but it makes a 2D face of where it was to where it is. Images won’t upload for some reason, so hopefully someone understands my weird description. Thanks!!!

Comment: See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Sounds like you have 2 edges occupying the exact same place and you are only selecting one of them when you select the face .  This can happen if you Extrude but don't actually move the newly extruded vertices. To remove these "doubles" : in edit mode select everything then open the Vertex menu > Merge vertices > By Distance.